# ggplot2: have 3 bar plot figures in one row and one more in the second row

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have simple data frame DF (4 row X 2 column)... I want to graph (bar plot ) for each row value in a separate graph. So, I can get 3 bar plot next each other (in one graph row) and the last graph comes in a new row (stretched over the whole row). I'm not sure why "count" axis is ranged from 0-1, I couldn't figure out the problem. Also, I tried to show the value on top of the bars by using `geom_text` and it seems not working....

my data from dput command:

```
structure(list(Test = structure(1:4, .Label = c("Source A", "Subject B", 
"Level C", "General rate"), class = "factor", scores = structure(c(4L, 
3L, 1L, 2L), .Dim = 4L, .Dimnames = list(c("General rate", "Level C", 
"Source A", "Subject B")))), Percentage = c(6.5, 29.1, 58.34, 
95.10)), .Names = c("Test", "Percentage"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

My code :

```
ggplot(DF, aes(Percentage)) + geom_bar(fill="gray") +
facet_wrap(~ Test)+
scale_fill_manual(values = c("gray80",
                             "gray70",
                             "gray60",
                             "gray20"))
```

I had to fill the colour manually because for some reasons `scale_colour_grey(start = 0, end = .9) or
    scale_fill_grey()` nor working with me....
[image]

I'm sure there many other good representations for the above data and totally opened for suggestions and new representations!!!

Comment: The reason why `scale_colour_grey(start = 0, end = .9)` and `scale_fill_grey()` are not working is the you have to put the `fill="gray"` part inside the `aes` part of the ggplot-code. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ggplot(DF, aes(y=Percentage, x= Test)) +geom_bar(stat="identity")+facet_wrap(~Test,scales="free_x")
```

`free_x`, is giving you a free scale on the x-axis.
As for what you want, You will need to create two different plots and then combine it with grid.arrange.
So subset the dataset without 'General rate' and with only 'General rate',
Create two plots and combine them. Code below

```
df.1 <-subset(DF, Test!="General rate") 
df.2 <-subset(DF, Test=="General rate")
#plot top
plot.top <-ggplot(df.1, aes(y=Percentage, x= Test)) +geom_bar(stat="identity")+facet_wrap(~Test,scales="free_x")
#plot bottom
plot.bottom <-ggplot(df.2, aes(y=Percentage, x= Test)) +geom_bar(stat="identity")+facet_wrap(~Test,scales="free_x")
library(gridExtra)
#Loading required package: grid
grid.arrange(plot.top, plot.bottom)
```

[image: The Result with grid.arrange]

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to use facet's? In this case i think it is much better to make just one barplot so you can compare the different groups better.

Example code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Test, y=Percentage, fill=Test)) + 
  geom_bar()
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: and yes unless there is a very specific reason you want the plot as described, I would go with this as it's easier to compare all on one plot. Facets are easier when you have one more level of grouping

Comment: You are right, but I need to show the general rate in a separate graph which is compute differently... Thanks for the comment @Jaap !!